# How to delete index from firestore using firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I check the firebase console for firestore,there is no delete option in the indexes page, only add is available.

[image: firestore]

How to delete them then, there are other questions on this but all are telling to find the delete option from here or do programmatically, but there is no option visible here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Remove indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#remove_indexes) to know how to delete indexes ( Menu icon will not appear except if you passed mouse there )

[image: Preview]

Comment: Yeah it worked,thank you very much.. can you please answer my other questions also